# AndroidStudio about HttpURLConnection

Tags: android-studio, httpurlconnection

This is my method!

```
private String logInActivity() {


    String userID = idText.getText().toString();
    String userPW = pwText.getText().toString();

    final String SERVER = "http://115.145.241.151:8080/AndroidCommunication/LoginActivity.jsp";

    if (userID != null && userPW != null) {


        final String QUERY = "?id=" + userID + "&pw=" + userPW;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL url = null;

        try {


            url = new URL(SERVER+QUERY);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();


            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line = reader.readLine();

            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {


            e.printStackTrace();
            return "3";
        }

    } else {


        Toast.makeText(GetReview.this, "Type all required info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return "2";
    }
}
```

I'm just practicing HttpURLConnection( by GET METHOD). I know i shouldn't send passwords or ids like this way but i'm just practicing my exercise. But I just don't get why this goes to an Exception. Please help!
I didn't type my addresses or anything wrong because I tried it, and server was on. I debugged it and the connection.connect(); doesn't seems to work.

my onCreate goes:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_review);


    pwText = findViewById(R.id.pwText);
    idText = findViewById(R.id.idText);
    resultText = findViewById(R.id.resultText);


    findViewById(R.id.btnLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new LoginAsyncTask().execute(logInActivity());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that issuing HTTP requests on the main thread is not allowed by android. That's why you are receiving a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception. To resolve this, you can use an `IntentService` to do that job for you and then broadcast the results back to the receiver (your activity).

If you don't know much about android Services, then have a read in the documentation, you'll find yourself using them time and time again...

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingAService

Comment: i don’t get ur 3rd feedback

Comment: @Peter what's the exception?

Comment: The exception is NetworkOnMainThreadException : I think it has to do with Leo's 3rd feedback. I used the AsyncTask and executed when I pressed the login button on the view.

Comment: I'll show you guys my onCreate as well ... it's updated

Comment: Thank you!! It's a great help